# How to increase efficiency of background jobs in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, delayed-job, rails-activejob

I'm currently running ActiveJob with DelayedJob as the backend for my background jobs on Heroku with **10** worker dynos. Daily, I need to run ~2000+ jobs which require lots of interaction with Google Sheets API that can take ~60+ seconds after the worksheet has run its calculations.

As each job could potentially take more than a minute to run, I'm wondering how I can increase the efficiency of these workers? It seems to me that these 10 workers can only take on 1 task at a time. Is it possible for 1 worker to take on my jobs? Would switching my background service to Sidekiq or another service allow these workers to take on more jobs?

Any insight would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Switching to sidekiq will decrease the overhead of the job processor, yes. Naturally, it can't bring down the time consumption of the Sheets API.

Comment: Thanks! I understand that Google is a limitation here, but will switching to Sidekiq allow more jobs to run at a given time? Right now 10 workers can run 10 jobs, is there way to get 10 workers to run 20 jobs?

Comment: I've heard stories of replacing 25 resque machines with just 1 sidekiq machine. YMMV.

Comment: For example: https://twitter.com/mperham/status/188016632071860224